# Vertically align text in a span with fixed width and height

Tags: html, css

I have a span with fixed width and height, but the length of the text inside it is not fixed, which can be either a single word or very long. How can I always vertically align the text to the middle of the span? For example, in my http://jsfiddle.net/w2cfkocv/1/, the second span only contains 1 word, but I want it to align in the middle of the span vertically. Thanks.

```
<table summary="dialogTitle" class="pageTitle">
<tr>
    <td style="">         
        <span id="headertitle"> title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title </span><br>
        <span id="headertitle"> title </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
#headertitle {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#000000;
    font-weight:bold;  
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    line-height: 25px;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    float: left;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: p/s: IDs **must** be unique in the HTML document. You are reusing the `headertitle` ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First don't use duplicate ID's(#) , and then change your `display:inline-block` to `display:table-cell`

here is a snippet:

```css
.headertitle {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 25px;
  display: table-cell;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table summary="dialogTitle" class="pageTitle">
  <tr>
    <td style="">
      <span class="headertitle"> title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title </span>
     
      <span class="headertitle"> title </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is the result:
[image]

Comment: I'm just using duplicate ID's(#) to represent different scenarios in my cases.    Changing that to table-cell, the fixed height doesn't seem to work. :(

Comment: look at my updated answer since it has a visualization from the snippet result,

Comment: @dippas Thanks for ur quick response, by fixed height I mean I want the span to be exactly 200px and hide the overflow text if any.

Comment: thats not your initial question. now your are asking different question.