# 100% height in a td, positioning the text in the vertical middle

Tags: html, css

I am currently using EvoPDF (HTML to PDF) to build up a report in C#.

In this report we have a table, looking something like this in the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bk48srw1/3/

with the important part:

```
<tr>
    <td>label for something</td>
    <td style="position:relative;" rowspan="99999">
    <div id="absolute">
        <div class="centerd">
        <span>value for all</span>
        </div>
    </div>    
    </td>
</tr>
```

The idea is that there are a variety of products, but they will have the same value in the second column, hence:

```
 rowspan="99999"
```

The client wants the styling (border and background) to span the height of the second column, with the text in the middle. I have tried the position absolute,  display:table, as well as vertical-align.

I cannot use a solution like [Vertically align text in a span with fixed width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28053138/vertically-align-text-in-a-span-with-fixed-width-and-height/)
because I have no idea what the height would be (there could be an arbitrary number of tr's)

How do I make the div 100% height of the td, with the text displaying in the middle?

My preference is not to use JS, seeing that this code doesn't see a browser at all.

For styling purposes, I need to have about 3px padding inbetween the td and the div, seeing that I cannot add cellspacing to only 1 td.

Comment: @Refammer as like this http://jsfiddle.net/bk48srw1/4/

Comment: @rohitAzad, apologies, added styling requirements into the code.

Answer (score 0):

Used to this change your html as like this

```css
td{
  width:50%;vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100% ">


<tr>
    <td>
      <table>
      <tr><td>label for something</td></tr>
      <tr>
    <td>label for this:</td>
    
</tr>
<tr>
<td>label for this:</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>label for this:</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>label for this:</td>

</tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td style="background:yellow; border: 1px solid black;text-align:center;">
    <table width="100%">
    <tr><td>value for all</td></tr>
    </table>
     
    </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/sjncndvn/2/

HTML markup:

```
<table style="width:100% ">
<tr>
    <td>label for something</td>
    <td style="position:relative;" rowspan="99999">
    <div id="absolute">
        <div class="centerd">
        <span>value for all</span>
        </div>
    </div>    
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label for this:</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>label for this:</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>label for this:</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>label for this:</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td{
  width:50%;
  display:table-cell ;
  vertical-align:middle ;
}
#absolute {
    width:100%;
    background:yellow;
    display:table;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.centerd {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
background-color:#pink;
}
```

Since #absolute no longer uses absolute positioning, you may want to change the ID name to something else.